# How do I access each value of a nested dictionary separately?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python dictionaries, my question is how can I access each value of a nested dictionary separately?

For example:

```
dist = {
    "9541258" :{"First" : "Barack",
                "Last"  : "Obama",
                "Age"   : "61",
                "DOB"   : "08/4/1961",
                "Fav_Co": "Dark Blue"
                }
}
```

Here the key is "9541258", and the values as per my understanding are "First" : "Barack", "Last" : "Obama"...etc.

Now I am trying to add more stuff to the dictionary from user input so I need to access each value i.e., First, Last, Age, DOB, Fav_color separately so I can add it to the dictionary as per user input.

So far I have tried this (I am printing the values instead of adding just to see and understand what each variable contains)

```
for keys, values in (dist.items()):
    print("Id\t:\t"+keys)
    for v1, v2 in values.items():
        print(v1 +"\t:\t"+v2)
```

However, v1 and v2 contain all the values together,
As in print(v1) outputs this;
First
Last
Age
DOB
Fav_col

I have tried this too, print(v1[0]), but that only outputs the first letter of each value i.e.,
F
L
A
D
F

I understand that according to this code
V1 is
First
Last
Age
DOB
Fav_col

and V2 is
Barack
Obama
61
08/4/1961
Dark Blue

So how do I access Barack, Obama, 61, 08/4/1961 separately?

p.s. Apologies for such a long explaination

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to do.  This code does print each value separately (on its own line).  Are you trying to access a *specific* value?  Which one?

Comment: Yes I am trying to access each value separately? As in if the user inputs this 

Sam
Reed
22
01/02/2000
Green

I want to add these values to the dictonary, on top of what it already has like a database, like this:

Id: #####

First : Sam
Last : Reed
Age : 22
DOB : 01/02/2000
Fav_Col : Green

Comment: That last sentence should be part of the original question -- all the rest of your explanation doesn't actually explain what you're trying to do, but in that one sentence you just summed it up perfectly!  :)

Comment: You need to edit your question. I'm marking this as unclear and voting to close. Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting your comment because it's really the crux of the question:

> As in if the user inputs this: `"Sam Reed 22 01/02/2000 Green"`
>
> I want to add these values to the dictonary, on top of what it already has like a database, like this: Id: ##### First : Sam Last : Reed Age : 22 DOB : 01/02/2000 Fav_Col : Green

Use `split()` to split the user's input so you can build a new dictionary out of it (zipping with the list of keys):

```
>>> new_entry = "Sam Reed 22 01/02/2000 Green"
>>> dist["######"] = dict(zip(("First", "Last", "Age", "DOB", "Fav_Co"), new_entry.split()))
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dist)
{'######': {'Age': '22',
            'DOB': '01/02/2000',
            'Fav_Co': 'Green',
            'First': 'Sam',
            'Last': 'Reed'},
 '9541258': {'Age': '61',
             'DOB': '08/4/1961',
             'Fav_Co': 'Dark Blue',
             'First': 'Barack',
             'Last': 'Obama'}}
```

You might also consider replacing your dictionaries with a `dataclass`, which gives you an easier way to construct new entries by simply passing a list of values (since the attributes and the order in which they can be specified as positional arguments are defined in the class itself):

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class Person:
...     First: str
...     Last: str
...     Age: str
...     DOB: str
...     Fav_Co: str
...
>>> {"######": Person(*new_entry.split())}
{'######': Person(First='Sam', Last='Reed', Age='22', DOB='01/02/2000', Fav_Co='Green')}
```

Comment: Yes doing this with a dataclass would make a lot of sense, and yes your method of using pprint works for what I am trying to do as well, thank you for the help!!

Comment: Based on your comment that you added after my answer, Sam's answer is correct. Sorry Sam, this question is very unclear and in this case you're right.